# SQL query for finding a few maximum dates based on a condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to find out the max `event_date` of each `user_role` per each user from the following table. So, basically for the first user John Doe he is only an Explorer and his last `event_date` was on 2021-7-7. The second one David Smith is both a Developer and a Viewer and for him, I want to query his last/max event date for each role. And print out the `event_category` and `event_name`.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | USER_NAME | USER_ROLE | EVENT_CATEGORY | EVENT_DATE | EVENT_NAME |  |
| 1 | John Doe | Explorer | condition_alerts | 2021-07-07 04:00:13.000 | run_alert |  |
| 2 | John Doe | Explorer | query | 2021-07-07 04:00:12.000 | run_query |  |
| 3 | John Doe | Explorer | condition_alerts | 2021-07-07 04:00:11.000 | detect_alert_drift |  |
| 4 | David Smith | Developer | scheduler | 2021-07-06 10:20:25.000 | update_scheduled_plan |  |
| 5 | David Smith | Viewer | scheduler | 2021-07-06 10:20:25.000 | update_scheduled_plan |  |
| 6 | David Smith | Developer | query | 2021-07-06 10:20:16.000 | run_query |  |
| 7 | David Smith | Viewer | dashboard_element | 2021-07-06 10:19:37.000 | update_dashboard_element |  |

The result should look like:

| ID | USER_NAME | USER_ROLE | EVENT_CATEGORY | EVENT_DATE | EVENT_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | Explorer | condition_alerts | 2021-07-07 04:00:13.000 | run_alert |
| 4 | David Smith | Developer | scheduler | 2021-07-06 10:20:25.000 | update_scheduled_plan |
| 5 | David Smith | Viewer | scheduler | 2021-07-06 10:20:25.000 | update_scheduled_plan |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach

```
SELECT
user_name,
user_role,
event_category,
event_date,
event_name
FROM myTable
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() over (
      partition by 
        user_name,
        user_role
      order by
        event_date DESC
    ) = 1
```

Comment: Do you want to partition by role? I think it's just user_name, right?

Comment: I need to partition per role as well because one user can have many roles. So this query works perfectly fine. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH maxima as (
   SELECT user_name, user_role, max(event_date) as max_evt
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY user_name, user_role
)

SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
JOIN maxima m
ON (
    m.user_name = t.user_name
    AND m.user_role = t.user_role
    AND m.max_evt = t.event_date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT ID, USER_NAME, USER_ROLE, EVENT_CATEGORY, EVENT_DATE, EVENT_NAME
FROM your_table A
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 ID AS topID
  FROM your_table B WHERE A.USER_NAME = B.USER_NAME
  ORDER BY EVENT_DATE DESC
) B
WHERE A.ID = B.topID
```